# Problems converting from printf scanf to cin cout

Tags: c++, syntax

For my homework assignment I have been been asked to take my previous project and change it from using `<stdio.h>` to `<iostream>` In the process I've had quite a few errors, and am just a little stuck on a few particular ones.

As far as my preprocessor directives go, I have included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
```

the error codes I have gotten specify specific lines of my code. One of the recurring errors I get is:

```
error: expected primary-expression before âfloatâ
```

This error came from these lines:

```
void PrintAverages(ofstream &output, int tot_employees, float tot_payrate, float tot_reghrs,
                   float tot_ovthrs, float tot_gross, float tot_fed, float tot_state,
                   float tot_ssi, float tot_def, float tot_net)
{      

    output << reportfile, "\n\nAverages:" << tot_payrate / tot_employees <<
              tot_reghrs / tot_employees << tot_gross / tot_employees <<
              tot_fed / tot_employees << tot_ssi / tot_employees << tot_net / tot_employees <<
              tot_ovthrs / tot_employees << tot_state / tot_employees << tot_def / tot_employees;
}
```

This is one of my external functions. The error code occurs several times with my other functions. I figure that the issue is similar to what ever is causing this one. If anyone could help point me in the right direction that would be great!

-Devin

Comment: Not sure, but this may have caused the problem: `reportfile, "\n\nAverages:"`

Comment: This is not an answer but you could simply `#include <cstdio>` and use `scanf()` instead of changing to `iostream`.

Comment: I have to try and stick with cin/cout

Comment: The provided code is not deficient in the stated problem. You need to show more code. Also, ignore `shg`, don't go anywhere near the C I/O functions.

Answer (score 0):

What type is `reportfile`?  The comma between `reportfile` and the `\n\nAverages:` string looks odd - shouldn't that be a `<<` also?

You'll want spaces between your floats, otherwise it will all run together.  Use `<< " " <<` between each `float` instead of just `<<`.

Comment: so possible something like this: output << "\n\nAverages:" << tot_payrate / tot_employees

Comment: Oh, i see. apparently reportfile is no unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
std::ofstream
```

as ofstream is declared in namespace std.

Also the comma after reportfile should be a `<<`.